Rendering H.264 video failed on Android
I am using this library for live streaming my camera's feed which uses video-codec H.264 and audio-codec ALAW. I am able to create the RTC peer connection successfully and receive both audio and video streams but unable to render the video using RTCVideoView.
The SDP packet received:
v=0
o=- 1495799811084970 1495799811084970 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
s=-
t=0 0
a=msid-semantic: iot
a=group:BUNDLE video audio
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 102
a=rtcp-fb:102 nack
a=rtcp-fb:102 nack pli
a=fmtp:96 profile-level-id=42e01f;level-asymmetry-allowed=1
a=fmtp:102 profile-level-id=42e01f;packetization-mode=1;level-asymmetry-allowed=1
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=rtpmap:102 H264/90000
a=ssrc:1 cname:webrtc-h264
a=sendrecv
a=mid:video
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp-mux
a=fingerprint:sha-256 1F:17:8B:92:C1:02:23:84:46:01:46:A5:0B:5C:AE:03:16:07:0A:8A:83:C6:C0:F7:A3:4B:A3:B5:F5:74:E5:69
a=setup:passive
a=ice-ufrag:ywiD
a=ice-pwd:ywiDaQPVV4S3Q7gT6iN94w29
a=candidate:1 1 UDP 1688444927 103.159.11.246 41887 typ srflx raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 0
a=candidate:2 1 UDP 2124652543 192.168.1.163 41887 typ host
m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVP 8
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=ptime:20
a=ssrc:4 cname:webrtc-pcma
a=sendrecv
a=mid:audio
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp-mux
a=fingerprint:sha-256 1F:17:8B:92:C1:02:23:84:46:01:46:A5:0B:5C:A

It is giving this error:
IMGSRV       com.example.webrtc_integration       E  :4879: IsTextureConsistent: IMGEGLImage is not consistent

Platform information

Flutter version: 3.19.5
Plugin version: 0.11.6+hotfix.1
OS: Android
OS version: 12

I have tried this in javascript for webpage and it is working. I want to render it in mobile app.

Resolved it by adding missing parameter packetization-mode=1 to a=fmtp:96 profile-level-id=42e01f;level-asymmetry-allowed=1 in sdp
